# Convert .bdf/.pcf font to .psf(u) for using as consolefont?

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, console, conversion

I am using Arch Linux.
Is it possible to convert a BDF or PCF font to a PSF font for use in console/CONSOLEFONT in rc.conf?
I haven't found anything that can do it,except bdf2psf which I got the source but couldn't find out how to use it, the man page was very hard to understand.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a how-to on [the Arch Linux boards](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=770649#p770649).

The basic command is:

```
./bdf2psf --fb yourbdffont.bdf \
  /whateverpath/current/usr/share/bdf2psf/standard.equivalents \
  /whateverpath/usr/share/bdf2psf/required.set+/whateverpath/usr/share/bdf2psf/useful.set \
  512 /path/to/nameofpsf-uni-11.psf
```

Comment: When trying to convert a .pcf font (from x3270), it failed for me with a "3270gt32.pcf: height 0 zero or too big" message.