# How can I make a psf font for the console from a otf one?

Tags: tty, fonts

I want to use the [Inconsolata font](http://levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) in the tty console, but I need to generate a `psf` font for that.

I found that there are two tools that should work, `otf2bdf` and `bdf2psf`, but every time I try to use the second one I get:

```
/usr/bin/bdf2psf: Inconsolata12.bdf: the width is not integer number.
```

Comment: This one looks extremely close to this Q: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21100/convert-bdf-pcf-font-to-psfu-for-using-as-consolefont

Comment: @slm, in my opinion, the question isn't actually about converting a bdf to a psf; it's about converting an otf to a psf. Going through bdf was just a tentative solution that the OP attempted.

Comment: see https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/7st7hz/any_way_to_convert_ttf_files_to_psf_files/

Comment: The `elsif` sequence on `$width` in `/usr/bin/bdf2psf` reveals that the program supports only 7, 8 and 9 dots width of the glyphs. Neither 12 nor 16 dots glyphs are seemingly supported. The software looks to be abandoned, as 12 and 16 are common widths on modern display devices.

Answer (score 9):

I'm actually trying to solve this very same problem. 
I worked it out by reading through this thread email exchange that took place some time ago.
visit [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=539108).

I still need to try this out . 
I'll report back if I get it to work.

Edit:
I was able to create the PSF font but have not tried to use it as a TTY font. I believe that was the implication of the question.
This is the way that I created the font (copied quasi-directly from the link).

1. Convert the OTF to BDF

   ```
   otf2bdf -r 72 -p 12 -c C /usr/share/fonts/truetype/incon...a/inconsolata.otf |
       sed -e "s/AVERAGE_WIDTH.*/AVERAGE_WIDTH 80/" > inconsolata-12.bdf
   ```

   (the sed invocation is required because bdf2psf sanity-checks the 
   AVERAGE_WIDTH property rather than the font bounding box, or checking 
   the DWIDTHs of the glyphs that it actually uses)
2. Convert the BDF file to a PSF file:

   ```
   bdf2psf inconsolata-12.bdf /usr/share/bdf2psf/standard.equivalents \
     /usr/share/bdf2psf/required.set+/usr/share/bdf2psf/useful.set 256 inconsolata-12.psf
   ```

That's it.

Comment: Which distribution is `required.set` part of? It's not in ubuntu or debian.