# Using TTY fonts taller than 32 pixels

Tags: linux, fonts, console

I have a HiDPI laptop and 32 pixels is a bit too small to be comfortably read. I was unable to find any larger fonts, so I decided to create my own.

This works fine for any font smaller than- or equal to 32px in height, but anything larger is rejected by setfont:

```bsh
> file FC-32.psf
FC-32.psf: Linux/i386 PC Screen Font v2 data, 256 characters, Unicode directory, 32x16
> file FC-33.psf 
FC-33.psf: Linux/i386 PC Screen Font v2 data, 256 characters, Unicode directory, 33x16
> # -----------
> setfont ./FC-32.psf
> # 32 is fine
> setfont ./FC-33.psf
Bad character height 33
> # (It also reject reasonable numbers like 48 and 64)
```

Is this a problem with my font? Am I doing something wrong? Is it a hard limit in the Linux console? I was unable to find any mention of a limit, nor any example of a larger font.

---

#### Test files and script used

[FC-32.psf.gz - 32x16, works](https://transfer.sh/1HsIl/FC-32.psf.gz)

[FC-33.psf.gz - 33x16, rejected](https://transfer.sh/CMJCW/FC-33.psf.gz)

My script for generating fonts is given below. It converts some `.otf` font into `.psf.gz` of configurable height. Math was trail and error, and may be specific to FiraCode.

I can also provide test files on request.

```bsh
#!/bin/zsh
# Based on this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161890/how-can-i-make-a-psf-font-for-the-console-from-a-otf-one

H=32 # <- FONT HEIGHT
PTS=12
(( W=H*5/10 ))
(( WIDTH = W*10 ))
(( DPI=H*60/PTS ))
COUNT=256
OUT=FC

otf2bdf -r $DPI -p $PTS -c C ./FiraCode-Regular.otf \
  | sed -e "s/AVERAGE_WIDTH.*/AVERAGE_WIDTH $WIDTH/" \
  > "$OUT.bdf"

bdf2psf --fb "$OUT.bdf" \
  /usr/share/bdf2psf/standard.equivalents \
  /usr/share/bdf2psf/ascii.set+/usr/share/bdf2psf/useful.set \
  $COUNT "$OUT.psf"

gzip "$OUT.psf" -f
```

Comment: Why can you not reduce your display resolution in order to make your pixels bigger?

Comment: @JdeBP I can, but native resolution is more desirable than up-scaling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m not sure the limit is explicitly documented in any user-oriented documentation, but it is baked in to the kernel. The [description for `fbcon_set_font`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.11/source/drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbcon.c#L2624) says:

```c
/*
 *  User asked to set font; we are guaranteed that
 *  a) width and height are in range 1..32
 *  b) charcount does not exceed 512
 *  but lets not assume that, since someone might someday want to use larger
 *  fonts. And charcount of 512 is small for unicode support.
 *
 *  However, user space gives the font in 32 rows , regardless of
 *  actual font height. So a new API is needed if support for larger fonts
 *  is ever implemented.
 */
```

and [`fbcon_get_font`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.11/source/drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbcon.c#L2462) processes characters in 32-line strides:

```c
    if (font->width <= 8) {
        j = vc->vc_font.height;
        for (i = 0; i < font->charcount; i++) {
            memcpy(data, fontdata, j);
            memset(data + j, 0, 32 - j);
            data += 32;
            fontdata += j;
        }
```

(with similar handling for fonts wider than 8 pixels).